# python logging: info level lastResort

Tags: python, logging, stdout, python-3.9

I'm working on a python library that uses `logging`. (Python 3.9) Now I import logging in each module separately (do not import it in `__init__.py`), and create a logger in each module using `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`

What and how should I set to ensure that, if `logging` is not imported in the code where my package is used, even info level log entries are printed on stdout/stderr.

I thought I'll have to use `logging.lastResort.setLevel(logging.INFO)`, and my assumption by including the following in my `__init__.py`

```py
import logging
logging.lastResort.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

But this - seemed not to provide the results I expected.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your library absolutely should not touch logging configuration. The program using the library should be in control of what it wants to do with `logging`.

Comment: yes, I agree, but ```logging.lastResort``` as I understand is designd for cases when the program using my library does not even import ```logging```. This is why I thought I should alter the lastResort there, if alterable at all.

Comment: Why should your library get to decide that it needs to litter the console?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. That's an extremely good point. :) But still, my library handles REST API calls and DB transactions, and a feedback on their success is a key, even if these messages are definitely not at ```warning``` level. They just inform the user of a successful transaction. The reason I use logger there is to give control to the user, but to default to info-level logs on the console seems to be a rational decision here.
(My main concern is more about the log entries of the libraries imported by my package.)

Comment: I think the user should just opt-in to getting those messages. All it takes is `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` on their end.

Comment: "if logging is not imported in the code where my package is used, even info level log entries are printed on stdout/stderr" - how do you expect to log at info level if logging hasn't been imported? What would you call the `info()` method on?

Comment: Thanks, @AKX, I see your point.
@VinaySajip, info() method is called in my package, where liggong is imported. If someone uses my package without importing ```logging```, everityhing at warning level and above will be pronted to stdout, since this is what ```logging.lastResort``` is for. At least according to my understanding of ```lastResort```